# Android Xamarin xml error

Tags: android, xml, xamarin

Please help me, I'm having trouble with this error

```
Error APT0000: String types not allowed (at 'entries' with value 'Item 1'). (APT0000) (Main.axml Line 2)
```

when I am trying to build the project. This is the line where the error it is supposed to be :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

I can't find out what the problem is, I haven't edited that line at all.

Edit :

The whole xml is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px">
<ToggleButton
    android:paddingLeft="25dp"
    android:paddingRight="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_width="225dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
    android:textOn="Showing Menus"
    android:textOff="Not Showing Menus" />
<RadioGroup
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1">
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="Italian"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton1" />
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="American"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton2" />
</RadioGroup>
<Spinner
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:layout_width="225dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:entries="Item 1" />
<RelativeLayout
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">
    <TextView
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:text="@string/ordered_food"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView1" />
    <TextView
        android:gravity="clip_horizontal"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:text="@string/ordered_food"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="175dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" />
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Edit 2 : The string.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="hello">Hello World, Click Me!</string>
<string name="app_name">UdemyXA4.4Task</string>
<string name="ordered_food">Ordered Food</string>
<string-array name="french_menu">
    <item>Frog Legs</item>
    <item>Snails</item>
    <item>Blue Cheese</item>
    <item>Grapes</item>
    <item>Red Wine</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="american_menu">
    <item>CheeseBurger</item>
    <item>Hamburger</item>
    <item>Chicken Nuggets</item>
    <item>Aligator Steak</item>
    <item>Meatballs</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

Comment: I've added the whole xml file in the question.

Comment: Also add your strings xml file. I think that's what the error is actuality referring to

Comment: Added the Strings.xml too in the question

Comment: Check out my answer. Your entries tag is pointing to a simple string but must be a reference to your array from strings.xml

Comment: Did you get it working? If my answer helped you I would be happy if you marked it as accepted via the little arrow on the left side of the answer.

Comment: Yes, it did the job. Sadly, I don't have enough rep.

Comment: Edit, nvm, confused it with the upvote button. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a string "Item 1" to your spinner. This is not supported.

Create a array definition in the file `/res/values/strings.xml`, like this:

```
<string-array name="my_spinner_items">
    <item>Item 1</item>
    <item>Item 2</item>
    <item>Item 3</item>
</string-array>
```

Then refer to this array-definition:

```
<Spinner
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:layout_width="225dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:entries="@array/my_spinner_items" />
```